# HTML/JS: Setting outputs dependant on what value from dropdown menu is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to set a value automatically dependant on which item from the drop down menu is selected.

Ideally I would like to have the 'enterSLA' value set automatically(instead of being inputted as it currently is) depending on which item is selected from the 'enterReq' drop-down menu.

e.g. if option 1 from enterReq is selected, set enterSLA value to 10.
if option 2 from enterReq is selected, set enterSLA value to 2

I have been trying to come up with a solution to this for some time now so if anyone is able to show me how this is done it would be much appreciated.

The code is also available via CodePen.io: https://codepen.io/dmcp123/pen/gOBYQRb

Thanks in advance!

```js
function Greeting(){
  console.time('time1');
    var temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append(temp);
 temp.val($('#result').text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  temp.remove();
    console.timeEnd('time1');
}

function AvayaRequest(){
  console.time('time1');
    var temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append(temp);
 temp.val($('#result2').text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  temp.remove();
    console.timeEnd('time1');
}

function AvayaRequest2(){
  console.time('time1');
    var temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append(temp);
 temp.val($('#result3').text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  temp.remove();
    console.timeEnd('time1');
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background: #f7ede2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.body-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 60px); /* Subtract the top and bottom margins */
    margin: 30px 0; /* Add 30px margin to the top and bottom */
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.label {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #111;
    margin-bottom: 5px; /* Add bottom margin to labels */
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="number"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px; /* Add left margin to input boxes */
}
.copy-text {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.copy-text input.text {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.copy-text button {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #5784f5;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}
.copy-text button:hover {
    background: #809ce2;
}
.copy-text button:active {
    background: #4668c7;
}
.copy-text button:before {
    content: "Copied";
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #5c81dc;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
}
.copy-text button:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #5c81dc;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: none;
}
.copy-text.active button:before,
.copy-text.active button:after {
    display: block;
}
.submit {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.submit input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #5784f5;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}
.submit input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: #809ce2;
}
.submit input[type="button"]:active {
    background-color: #4668c7;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #5784f5;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
footer p {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AAV Copy/Paste Help Sheet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body-wrapper">
       <div class="container">
<form>

 <h3>Ticket/Customer inputs</h3>   
  
<div>Customer Name:</div>
<input name="enterName" id="enterName" type="text">
  
<br>
  
<div>INC Number:</div>
<input name="enterInc" id="enterInc" type="text">  

<br><br>  

  <h3>Request inputs(if applicable)</h3>  
  
<div>Request type(e.g. to "update lead lines"):</div>
<select name="enterReq" id="enterReq">
  <option id =1 value="change existing extension/user details">Change existing extension/user details</option>
  <option id =2 value="create an additional leads line">Create an additional leads line</option>
  <option id =3 value="create an exclusive leads line">Create an exclusive leads line</option>
  <option id =4 value="add/remove/disconnect a DID line">Add/remove/disconnect a DID line</option>
  <option id =5 value="remove/repurpose an existing lead line">Remove/repurpose an existing lead line</option>
  <option id =6 value="create/modify a ring group">Create/modify a ring group</option>
  <option id =7 value="create/modify ACD call routing">Create/modify ACD call routing</option>
  <option id =8 value="change office announcement/greeting">Change office announcement/greeting</option>
  <option id =9 value="add/remove/modify IVR">Add/remove/modify IVR</option>
  <option id =10 value="modify the amount of rings on incoming calls">Modify the amount of rings on incoming calls</option>
  <option id =11 value="change which email(s) receive voicemail notifications">Change which email(s) receive voicemail notifications</option>
  <option  id =12 value="modify/update the voicemail mailbox destination">Modify/update the voicemail mailbox destination</option>
  <option id =13 value="update user access to service observe">Update user access to service observe</option>
</select>
  
<div>Request SLA(in days):</div>
<input name="enterSla" id="enterSla" type="number" value="">
   

<div>RITM Number:</div>
<input name="enterRITM" id="enterRITM" type="text"> 

<div style="margin-top:10px;" class="submit">
<input value="submit" id="submit_this" type="button">
</div>
</form>
<br>

<script name=Greeting id=Greeting>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var greeting = function(name) {
            var name = $('#enterName').val();
            name = 'Hi there' + ' ' + name+ ", I hope you're keeping well :). Just provide what you can from the above please so I can look further into your issue.";
      
            console.log('Hi there' + '' + name + ", I hope you're keeping well :). Just provide what you can from the above please so I can look further into your issue.");
            $('#result').text(name);
        };

    $('#submit_this').click(function(e) { 
      greeting();
                              
        
        //prompt('Hi there,' + '' + name);
    });
});
</script>
  
<script name=AvayaRequest id=AvayaRequest>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var AvayaRequest = function(inc) {
            var inc = $('#enterInc').val();
            var incType = $('#enterReq').val();
            var incSla = $('#enterSla').val();
            var incRITM = $('#enterRITM').val();
            inc = 'Thank you for contacting the ATSC. Your request to ' + incType + ".is now with our vendor, Avaya. Your new ticket number is " + incRITM + ". Within " + incSla + " Business days, Avaya will email you to advise your issue has been resolved. The Voice team are currently working through a backlog of requests and will work your request as soon as possible, this may cause a breach in the agreed SLA. "
      
     + "Please be aware you will receive an email advising " + inc + " has been resolved. This is due to your new ticket being processed with Avaya." + " Bear in mind the " + incSla + " days is simply a maximum SLA and requests are normally processed much sooner dependant on demand. Just keep an eye on your emails for further updates."      
      ;
      
            console.log('Thank you for contacting the ATSC. Your request to' + '' + inc + ", I hope you're keeping well :). Just provide what you can from the above please so I can look further into your issue.");
            $('#result2').text(inc);
        };

    $('#submit_this').click(function(e) { 
      AvayaRequest();
                              
        
        //prompt('Hi there,' + '' + name);
    });
});
</script>
  
<script name=AvayaRequest2 id=AvayaRequest2>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var AvayaRequest2 = function(inc) {
            var inc = $('#enterInc').val();
            var incType = $('#enterReq').val();
            var incSla = $('#enterSla').val();
            var incRITM = $('#enterRITM').val();
            inc = 'Thank you for contacting the ATSC. Your request to ' + incType + ".is now with our vendor, Avaya. Your new ticket number is " + incRITM + ". Within " + incSla + " Business days, Avaya will email you to advise your issue has been resolved. The Voice team are currently working through a backlog of requests and will work your request as soon as possible, this may cause a breach in the agreed SLA. "
      
     + "Please be aware you will receive an email advising " + inc + " has been resolved. This is due to your new ticket being processed with Avaya." + " Bear in mind the " + incSla + " days is simply a maximum SLA and requests are normally processed much sooner dependant on demand. Just keep an eye on your emails for further updates."      
      ;
      
            console.log('Thank you for contacting the ATSC. Your request to' + '' + inc + ", I hope you're keeping well :). Just provide what you can from the above please so I can look further into your issue.");
            $('#result2').text(inc);
        };

    $('#submit_this').click(function(e) { 
      AvayaRequest2();
                              
        
        //prompt('Hi there,' + '' + name);
    });
});
</script>
  
<div id=Greetings>
  <h2>Greetings</h2>  
  <button class="fa fa-clone"     type="button" onclick="Greeting();" </button>
  
<div class="copy-text" id="result"></div>

  </div>
  
<div id=requests> 
  <h2>Requests</h2>
  <button class="fa fa-clone"     type="button" onclick="AvayaRequest();" </button>
  
<div class="copy-text" id="result2"></div>

  </div>  
  
<div id=requests2> 
  <button class="fa fa-clone"     type="button" onclick="AvayaRequest2();" </button>
  
<div class="copy-text" id="result3"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <P>Demo</p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to attach an event listener to the `#enterReq` select menu, so that, when the selected option of the `#enterReq` select menu changes, the id of the selected option will be mapped to a value to set for the `#enterSla` input. The code to do this would look like:

```
$(function () {
  $('#enterReq').on('change', function () {
    const reqId = Number($(this).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
    let slaValue;
    
    if (reqId === 1) {
      slaValue = 10;
    } else if (reqId === 2) {
      slaValue = 2;
    }
    // other conditional mappings go here
    
    $('#enterSla').val(slaValue || null);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

Note: The purpose of `.trigger('change')` is to fire the event on page load so that the `#enterSla` will get updated based on the initially selected option of `#enterReq`.

[Here](https://codepen.io/76484/pen/PoyzwPa) is a fork of your Codepen.